# Dependant spinners in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am using Depandent Spinner in android studio. They are working well The child spinner is showing the correct data of against selected value of parent spinner but when I pass spinner text to Firebase Realtime database, it only pases the text of first index of childcat(child spinner), even when other item is selected. Text of main cat(parent spinner) is passing well in firebase database.
Here is the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        emailtext = findViewById(R.id.emailtext);
        // category = findViewById(R.id.cat);
        fname = findViewById(R.id.fullnametext);
        organization = findViewById(R.id.org);
        maincat = findViewById(R.id.categories);
        childcat = findViewById(R.id.categoryitem);
        signup = findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);


        ArrayAdapter adp1=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Categories,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adp1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        maincat.setAdapter(adp1);
       maincat.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                final String email = emailtext.getText().toString();
                //  final String fcategory = category.getText().toString();
                final String name = fname.getText().toString();
                //final String con_pass = organization.getText().toString();
                final String cat=category;
                final String subcat=specific;
                Map<String, Object> Users = new HashMap<>();
                Users.put("Name", name);
                Users.put("Email", email);
                Users.put("Category", cat);
                Users.put("SubCategory", subcat);

                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").push().setValue(Users).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Log.i("vvv", "oncomplete");
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.i("nnn", "OnFailure:" + e.toString());
                    }
                });


            }
        });

        ;

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        category=maincat.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(i==0){
            ArrayAdapter adp2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Natural_Disasters, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            childcat.setAdapter(adp2);
        }
        if(i==1){
            ArrayAdapter adp2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Medical, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            childcat.setAdapter(adp2);
        }
        if(i==2){
            ArrayAdapter adp2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Events, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            childcat.setAdapter(adp2);
        }
        if(i==3){
            ArrayAdapter adp2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Career_supporting, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            childcat.setAdapter(adp2);
        }
        if(i==4){
            ArrayAdapter adp2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.SocialIssues, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            childcat.setAdapter(adp2);
        }
        specific=childcat.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add these 3 lines in on create

```
ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
mDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
mDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

add two lines in your signup function

```
mDialog.show(); //to show activity indicator
mDialog. dismiss(); //to hide activity indicator
```

here is example with your code

```
signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                final String email = emailtext.getText().toString();
                //  final String fcategory = category.getText().toString();
                final String name = fname.getText().toString();
                //final String con_pass = organization.getText().toString();
                final String cat=category;
                final String subcat=specific;
                Map<String, Object> Users = new HashMap<>();
                Users.put("Name", name);
                Users.put("Email", email);
                Users.put("Category", cat);
                Users.put("SubCategory", subcat);

                mDialog.show();//to show activity indicator


FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").push().setValue(Users).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            mDialog. dismiss();//to hide activity indicator
                            Log.i("vvv", "oncomplete");
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.i("nnn", "OnFailure:" + e.toString());
                        }
                    });
    
    
                }
            });
```

Comment: you can also make ProgressDialog mDialog; global variable